# Rcpp Library Won't Build (Can't find Compiler) on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, r, ubuntu, rcpp

I have a package that depends on `Rcpp` and uses two other libraries compiled from sub-directories in `src/`.  The package builds fine on Mac OSX using a clang compiler.  However, on an RStudio Ubuntu server, it fails to build.  The build's first two steps (creating the static libraries in the sub directories to link in) work fine and I can see sensible build commands like the following taking place:

```
g++ -Wall -I../../inst/include/ --std=c++11 -lhts -L../htslib/ -lz -lm -c -o someLibFile.o someLibFile.cpp
```

However, in the very last step of the build process where it tries to build the `Rcpp` code and bind to the library, for some reason it appears to compleletey fail to put the compiler command in front (`g++`) and only outputs the second half of the command.

```
 -o mypackage.so RcppExports.o temp.o -lhts -lpbbam -Lpbbam/ -L/htslib/ -Lpbbam/ -L/mnt/software/r/R/3.1.1/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
```

In contrast, on the Mac it builds just fine, appending `clang++` and other flags in front of this final command:

```
 clang++ -std=c++11 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o pbbamr.so LoadData.o RcppExports.o temp.o -lhts -lpbbam -Lpbbam/ -Lhtslib/ -Lpbbam/ -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
```

How do I make it use the g++ compiler on Ubuntu at this step?  I have a custom `Makevars` file, but it is there just to build the dependencies in the sub-directory, so I don't know why that would cause any problems (since it works on Mac OSX).

**More Information**

The compiler seems to be found if I delete my `Makevars` file.  However, the `Makevars` file I am using is essentially a direct copy of the example given in the R extensions guide with one addition to enable C++11:

```
 CXX_STD = CXX11
.PHONY: all mylibs

all: $(SHLIB)
    $(SHLIB): mylibs

mylibs:
    (cd subdir; make)
```

With the line `CXX_STD` removed, it does stick a compiler in front of the command.

Comment: Maybe try to do something like `export CXX=g++` and then run the build process again?

Comment: If you're compiling with C++11 support, you may need to set the `CXX1X` environment variable.

Comment: Genius!!!! Setting export CXX1X=yes fixes the lack of a compiler, I'll need to  figure out how to get the compiler options back, but that seems to be heading in the right direction

Comment: I think you need to use e.g. `CXX1XFLAGS` -- [R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Using-C_002b_002b11-code) will be helpful here.

Comment: Actually, false alarm, it turns out the flag doesn't do anything, it was deleting the Makevars file that allowed it to proceed on the difficult machine

Comment: @KevinUshey thanks though! You clued me in to the fact that if I remove CXX_STD = CXX11 from the Makevars file, it does proceed

Comment: The C++11 compiler is *not* `CXX` but `CXX1X`.  Look **closely** at `$RHOME/etc/Makeconf`.  Better still copy a working C++11 package eg my [RcppTOML](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcpptoml) one.

Comment: Working with subdirectories is far from trivial.  I would recommend starting simpler.

Comment: Thanks! It appears on the working machines the values CXX1X, CXX1XFLAGS, CXX1XSTD are set in Makeconf, but not on the failing machine.  Manually adding them doesn't help so far.  Point well taken about starting simpler though, I have never had a problem in my other projects without a Makevars file or subdirectories, but unfortunately I need to take a dependency on a parsing library in this case (it's an obscure binary format and it would be too costly to reinvent the parser)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel as an aside, it appears on this machine install_github("eddelbuettel/rcpptoml") produces a similar error

Comment: Your machines are ancient.  R 3.0.0 didn't even have C++11 support. Work on recent R; everything will work.  On ancient R you may be on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by using an outdated/unusual R installation which has poor support for C++11.  The best way to resolve his is to upgrade to  a more recent version of R, or use a standard R install (`sudo apt-get install r-base-dev`).  A poor work around is described below.

**Problems Cause and Bad Work Around**

When writing R extension that use C++11, one often sets `CXX_STD = CXX11` in the `Makevars` file or list `SystemRequirements: C++11` in the `DESCRIPTION` file.  These will trigger R to use the compiler set by the following flags in the `Makeconf` file (located at `file.path(R.home(), "etc/Makeconf")`).

```
CXX1X
CXX1XFLAGS
CXX1XPICFLAGS
CXX1XSTD
```

Note that some of these may be set in this file, but not all of them might be there indicating a problem.  In the event there is a problem with these settings or they are not set, R appears to use the empty string "" as the compiler/linker for the C++ code, leading to the problem shown above where no compiler argument is given.

If upgrading is not an option and you need to deploy on a known machine, one work around is to manually setup for C++11 by making a more idiosyncratic `Makevars` file.  For example, you could:

- Remove the `CXX_STD=CXX11` line from the `Makevars` file.
- Remove `SystemRequirements: C++11` from the `DESCRIPTION` file.
- Add `--std=c++11` and any other requirements needed to `PKG_CPPFLAGS`, `PKG_CFLAGS`, `PKG_CXXFLAGS` or whatever variable is being used to compile your code, to manually set the needed flags (assuming the machine's compiler actually does support C++11).

The above solution is not particularly robust, but can be used as a work around in case the machine cannot be upgraded.

Thanks to @DirkEddelbuettel for not only writing `Rcpp` but being willing to support it on StackOverflow and help with issues like this.

Answer (score 1):

Briefly:

- What is your R installation?  You should probably run the binaries provided by Michael via CRAN; they are based on my Debian upload; I run these too on a bunch of machines
- The reason is that R 'remembers' its compile-time settings via `$RHOME/etc/Makefconf`.  This should just be `CXX=g+=`.
- When you install `r-base-dev` (from Ubuntu or the newer version from CRAN) you also get the `build-essential` package as well as all common dependencies.  With that things just work.

If however you are doing something special or local, well then you have to deal with your local changes.  The basic Ubuntu setup is used by thousands of people and daily jobs--including eg Travis builds for countless GitHub repos.

Comment: Thanks!  Following your suggesting, trying on a fresh Ubuntu build with R version 3.0.1 works fine, however on the machine I am trying to deploy to with R 3.1.1 the same problem occurs.  I am not sure what's changed, but will try to track down any differences I can find.

Comment: I don't suppose there is a quick flag to get any more information about how Rcpp forms the final build command? The Makefconf files on both installs appears the same, and I am not sure what code is executed during the package build that is causing the problem

Comment: It is all just `R CMD INSTALL ...` and nothing special happens from the Rcpp side.   You are working on systems with (very !!) non-standard setups.  This is not an Rcpp issue per se, it just hits you trying to compile something also using Rcpp.

Comment: Thanks again for all the help, this machine is definitely non-standard (not my choice).  Do you know if there is anyway to view the Makefile R generates on the fly during install? I suspect if I could see that I would be in good shape